# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. while importing GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, anaconda

How can I fix the error and get GeoPandas to work on my Win10 machine?

Solutions tried:

1. New environment following instructions [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/879)
2. Uninstalling and reinstalling Geopandas

Detailed error:

```
import geopandas as gpd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\**\Anaconda3\envs\rider_env\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopandas._config import options  # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\**\Anaconda3\envs\rider_env\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_config.py", line 126, in <module>
    default_value=_default_use_pygeos(),
  File "C:\Users\**\Anaconda3\envs\rider_env\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_config.py", line 112, in _default_use_pygeos
    import geopandas._compat as compat
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\**\Anaconda3\envs\rider_env\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_compat.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pyproj
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\**\Anaconda3\envs\rider_env\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    import pyproj.network
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\**\Anaconda3\envs\rider_env\lib\site-packages\pyproj\network.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pyproj._network import (  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: I don't use Anaconda, but in vanilla python on windows environments, I find I always have to first install some dependencies of geopandas (Fiona, GDAL, Rtree) using this site of pre-compiled wheels: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just open anaconda CLI. activate your environment and run this command:

```
pip uninstall pyproj && pip install pyproj
```

This should resolve your issue with the information that you have provided.

Comment: Great! it works. It is strange that Geopandas default installation has pyproj issue.